# How to correctly bandpass filter in frequency with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

i'm pretty new to matlab and signal processing, but I am working on a project and I am stuck. My goal is to do a band-pass fast Fourier transform (FFT) filter with cut-off frequencies of 0.5 Hz and 3 Hz from a real signal. My input signal is a signal sampled ad 405Hz and of around 35000 samples. My implementation looks like this:

```
%ZFiltered = My signal 
filtered = bandpass(fft(zFiltered), [0.5 3], sampling_frequency);
res = ifft(filtered);

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(zFiltered)

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(abs(res))
```

My questions are: Why do I get a signal which contains also imaginary part? Why does it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFiWA.png) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is unclear to me; here are three different approaches that your question hints at

1. filter your raw signal with a band-pass filter as your code attempts to do
2. use the [`fft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) and [`ifft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) functions to filter your raw signal
3. calculate the coefficients of a digital filter that would act as a band-pass filter when used with the [`filter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) function

---

**Approach 1**: filtering with `bandpass` function

Referring to the [`bandpass` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bandpass.html), you would use your original signal and specify the filter band and sampling frequency as in:

```
filtered_signal = bandpass(zFiltered,[freq_low freq_high],sample_freq);
plot(zFiltered); hold on;
plot(filtered_signal);
```

where the inputs are the

- `zFiltered` : original (unfiltered signal)
- `freq_low=0.5` : lowest frequency in Hz of the band pass range`
- `freq_high=3` : highest frequency in Hz of the band pass range
- `sample_freq=405` : the sampling frequency in Hz

Your approach using digital fast Fourier transform function [`fft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) produces complex results because you are looking at the actual components computed by the transform (which by definition are complex having both real and imaginary parts). You can compute the power of the signal with:

```
P = abs(res/n).^2;
```

which gives you the power of the signal for each frequency represented in the Fourier transform (see the `fft` function docs [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) for more information).

---

**Approach 2**: Filtering with `fft` `ifft` functions

Use the Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform functions to filter the signal. The steps here are to use `fft` to get the signal into the frequency domain. Set the elements you want filtered to zero and then apply the inverse Fourier transform (`ifft`) to get the filtered signal. Each component represents a given discrete frequencies in the range between 0Hz and `F_s/2` that contributes to the signal. Set components of the FFT you want to suppress to zoro and apply `ifft` to get back a filter signal. Please see the `fft` [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) and `ifft` [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html) for information on these functions and some of the intricacies of working with signals in the frequency domain.

---

**Approach 3**: Filtering with the coefficeints of the standard difference equation

Computing the coefficients of a digital band pass filter.  This approach calculates the coefficients (vectors `A` and `B`) of the standard difference equation (see [`filter` docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) for details). An example of a function that does this is `butter` which gives the coefficients that represent a Butterworth filter of a given frequency. You could also look at the `designfilt` function for more options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the goal is the third approach you have described actually, my main problem is how to filter the signal after the fft. When you say to set elements at zero you mean to create a vector of zero and ones and filter with it?

Comment: @alberto : I've edited the question with more details. I changed the order of the different approaches. Please read the docs for the `fft` and `ifft` functions.  Basically, you need to take the result of the `fft` transform (`fft_componnents`)  and do `fft_components(suppres_frequency_indices)=0` for the frequencies you want to filter out. does that make sense?